# Using "!=" for a Tic-Tac-Toe program for tie condition

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Making a Tic-Tac-Toe program for my programming class: Currently using this line of code to check for a tie, I know it's sloppy:

```
}
    else if(board[0][0] != '*' && board[0][1] != '*' && board[0][2] != '*' && board[1][0] != '*' && board[1][1] != '*' && board[1][2] != '*' && board[2][0] != '*' && board[2][1] != '*' && board[2][2] != '*')
        cout << "It's a tie!\n" ;
    return false;
}
```

The rest of my win conditions return a true (there's a lot of them, I know there's a better way to check but don't know how). Anyway, if I return a true, it will end the program on the first iteration. The loop I am running is:

```
do {
        cout << "Player X's bid (" << tokens1 << " tokens left): " ;
        bid1 = checkBid(lowBound, tokens1);
        cout << "Player O's bid (" << tokens2 << " tokens left): " ;
        bid2 = checkBid(lowBound, tokens2);
        cout << endl;

        playerTurn(bid1, bid2, board, tokens1, tokens2);

        showBoard(board);

    } while(!gameOver(board));
```

Tried using

```
while(gameOver != true);
```

or

```
while(gameOver != false);
```

and gave me bunch of errors. Trying to figure out why my current tie checker isn't working correctly. The win checks work fine.

If I run the program when  the tie check is return false, it will give the message "It's a tie!" but it will not stop the program. If I run it when the tie check is return true, it will end it the first iteration.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context.  What is the declaration of gameOver?

Comment: The function is  bool gameOver(char board[3][3]). What else do you need for me to provide?

Comment: Is the code in your first snippet from inside that function?  I suggest posting the whole thing.

Comment: Actually I might have fixed it, I forgot to include a pair of curly brackets, will check in a second

Comment: With your shown code, you only display message in case of tie, and you always return `false` (the return is not in the same block as the message).